# Is it possible to tilt/rotate text in VS10 Report Designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, report, report-designer

Is it possible, to have text written vertical in a TextBox(or other component prehaps), in Visual Studio 2010 Report Designer? (Like normal text, just tiltet 90 degrees clockwise). I could't find anything under properties, but I might have missed it.

If so, how? :)

Comment: Pretty sure that's not possible.  You need to consider moving to a full-featured report designer beyond the simple one provided by VS when you have needs like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the feature. It can be done with the ´WrittenMode´setting.

It can be found in the complete VS-property window. I don't think it's in the popupwindow-property for a Rectangle.

Comment: Could you add an image or the steps you used?

Comment: If you look in VS property-window, you will find the WrittingMode property for a TextBox.

Comment: Remember, if you right-click on a component in the designer to get the property, it will only hold the most commen once. The complete list will be in the VS property-window. :)

Answer (score 2):

If it is something that does not need to be filled with data you could use a image.

Comment: Sometimes the most brilliant solutions is the most simple. Please give this gentlemen +1 :)